# Easy Mock - How to?

Tags: testing, junit, mocking, easymock

I am trying easyMock test few classes / interface methods. Methods with parameters, trying to capture the parameter, but getting one or other error. If I manage to only record one expectation, it doesn't even capture anything in the parameter pipe, where if i use the following approach, I am getting error as follows the code.

```
@Test
public void testFireChannelInitializer() throws Exception 
{
    expect(c.pipeline()).andReturn(pipeline).times(1);
    channelListener.fireChannelInitializer(EasyMock.capture(pipe), serverHandler);
    EasyMock.replay(c, pipeline, channelListener);

    initializer.initChannel(c);

    verifyAll();
    assertEquals(4, pipe.getValues().size());
    assertTrue(pipe.getValues().get(0) instanceof LoggingHandler);
    assertTrue(pipe.getValues().get(0) instanceof ObjectEncoder);
    assertTrue(pipe.getValues().get(0) instanceof ObjectDecoder);
    assertTrue(pipe.getValues().get(0) instanceof ServerHandler);
}
```

Results in Error

> testFireChannelInitializer(com.obolus.generic.impl.DefaultChannelListenerTest)
>   Time elapsed: 3.812 sec  <<< ERROR! java.lang.IllegalStateException: 2
>   matchers expected, 1 recorded. This exception usually occurs when
>   matchers are mixed with raw values when recording a method:   foo(5,
>   eq(6));   // wrong You need to use no matcher at all or a matcher for
>   every single param:   foo(eq(5), eq(6));  // right    foo(5, 6);  // also
>   right     at
>   org.easymock.internal.ExpectedInvocation.createMissingMatchers(ExpectedInvocation.java:51)
>     at
>   org.easymock.internal.ExpectedInvocation.(ExpectedInvocation.java:40)
>     at org.easymock.internal.RecordState.invoke(RecordState.java:78)    at
>   org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:40)
>     at
>   org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:94)
>     at
>   org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:97)
>     at
>   com.obolus.generic.impl.DefaultChannelListener$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2da02970.fireChannelInitializer()
>     at
>   com.obolus.generic.impl.DefaultChannelListenerTest.testFireChannelInitializer(DefaultChannelListenerTest.java:63)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:242)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)

Any idea whats wrong or How to use easy mock? No good documentation or examples around.

Answer (score 1):

The easymock website has a [user guide](http://easymock.org/user-guide.html) but they redid their website recently and the guide isn't as complete as it used to be.

I think your problem might be you have to do a capture AND an argument matcher.

From the user guide:

> Matches any value but captures it in the Capture parameter for later access. You can do and(someMatcher(...), capture(c)) to capture a parameter from a specific call to the method. You can also specify a CaptureType telling that a given Capture should keep the first, the last, all or no captured values.

So you might need to do an `and( capture(..), paramMatcher)`

Also EasyMock has an annoying API "feature" where if you use one argument matcher in a method call, then all the arguments must also be wrapped in matchers even if it's `eq()`.  I think that's what your exception is complaining about.  So I think those are your two problems.

I'm not sure what your method signature looks like so I will assume it's

```
void fireChannelInitializer(Object, ServerHandler);
```

after using static imports to import `EasyMock.*`

```
channelListener.fireChannelInitializer( 
                and(capture(pipe), isA(Object.class)), //captures the argument to `pipe` Capture object
                  eq(serverHandler));
```

Comment: I was able to test that with this `channelListener.fireChannelInitializer(capture(pipe), eq(serverHandler));`. but the problem is, I can assert it against only checking instanceof, but there is no value in it.

Comment: How are you creating the `pipe` Capture object?  And did you try using the `and()` construct?

Comment: I am using it like this `Capture<ChannelPipeline> pipe = Capture.newInstance(CaptureType.ALL);`. Yes I tried using and too.